# how can i generate enrollment token for elasticsearch to connect with kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, token, kibana, user-enrollment

I am having running elastic-search on my Kubernetes cluster with host `http://192.168.18.35:31200/`. Now I have to connect my elastic search to the kibana. For that an enrollment token needs to be generated but how?
When I login to the root directory of elastic-search from kibana dashboard and type the following command to generate a new enrollment token, it shows the error:

[image]

```
command : bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
error: bash: bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token: No such file or directory
```

I have created a file elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token inside the bin directory and gave full permission. Still, no tokens are generated.
Have any ideas on enrollment token guys?

Comment: Have you tried `./bin/...` (i.e. add `./` ad the beginning of the command). If not, are you sure you have the `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token` script in your `bin` folder? If that's not the case, you're running ES 7 (and not ES8)

Comment: yeah my es is 7.9 and kibana is 8

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that you are on debian/ ubuntu, this should help

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/

then

./elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
```

Comment: Note that the OP not running ES8, but ES 7.9 and Kibana 8 which are not compatible

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running ES 7.9, you also need Kibana 7.9. You cannot run Kibana 8 on ES 7.9.

That's the reason why you don't have the `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token` script in your bin folder, since that's new in ES8

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on Docker Desktop, say on MacOS:

1. Make sure both Kibana and ElasticSearch are running like so:

[image]

2. Click to open the running ElasticSearch Docker instance.
3. Open the Terminal tab on the Docker Desktop and run the following command: `bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana`

**Note:** The token is only valid for 30mins.

Get more info from the docs: [Create Enrolment Token](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-enrollment-token.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [enrollment flow for configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-stack-security.html) is available in version 8.0 and onwards only and is designed to work only with the TLS configuration that is generated automatically on the first start of the node.

You can still use the documentation to setup TLS manually and configure Kibana to connect to your elasticsearch cluster as you would do in previous versions, this is always supported too.

I’d strongly suggest that you look into using [ECK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html) and take advantage of the documentation available.